# How do I delete tables matching a search criterion?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I know I can delete tables using

```
delete some_table_name from `.
```

But suppose I have a large number of tables, and want to delete all tables that, say, begin with `prefix_` and end with `_suffix`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require this functionality often, I suggest that you define a `drop` function as follows:

```
q)drop:![`.;();0b;](),
```

This function will take one or more table names as symbols and delete them.   Combined with a selector function it can be used to delete by pattern

```
q)drop{x where x like"prefix_*_suffix"}tables[]
```

You can also define a `drop_matching` function

```
q)drop_matching:drop{a where(a:tables[])like x}@
```

that will do the job in one swoop:

```
q)drop_matching"prefix_*_suffix"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional form of `delete` (see [here](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/#delete)):

```
/ create some tables 
q)`a_one`a_two`b_one`b_two set\:([] x:til 10)
    `a_one`a_two`b_one`b_two
q)tables[]
    `s#`a_one`a_two`b_one`b_two

/ find table names matching "a_*" and delete them from root namespace
q)![`.;();0b;{x where x like "a_*"} tables[]]
    `.
q)tables[]
    `s#`b_one`b_two
```